# how to generate small multiples in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some problem with making small multiples in d3, even after reading several tutorials such as [this](http://bl.ocks.org/officeofjane/7315455). I intend to make a set of 2x2 bar charts, yet there's something wrong in my code and nothing shows up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Width and height
    var w = 600;
    var h = 250;
    var margin = {
      top: 45,
      right: 100,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20
    };

    var dataset = [{
        "type": "A",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "type": "B",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "type": "C",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "D",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "A",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "B",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "type": "C",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 5
      },
      {
        "type": "D",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 1
      }
    ];
    var data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      })
      .entries(dataset);

    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(d3.range(data.length))
      .rangeRound([0, w])
      .paddingInner(0.05);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
      .range([0, h]);

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.idx);
      })
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

I intended to make a bar chart for each group and lay it out on a 2x2 grid. but after nesting and appending multiple svgs, nothing appears.

Thanks for pointing out what went wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the problems:

You don't have a container with the ID `vis`. Create it:

```
<div id="vis"></div>
```

The height of the bars is incorrect. It should be:

```
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d.value);
})
```

However, the main problem is the domain of the `y` scale. Since you have nested arrays, it should be:

```
.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d3.max(d.values, e => e.value))])
```

Have in mind that your code will create the same scale for **all** the small multiples. Sometimes the designer wants different scales for each small multiple...

Here is the code with those changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Width and height
    var w = 300;
    var h = 150;
    var margin = {
      top: 5,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 5,
      left: 10
    };

    var dataset = [{
        "type": "A",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "type": "B",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "type": "C",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "D",
        "idx": 1,
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "A",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "B",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "type": "C",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 5
      },
      {
        "type": "D",
        "idx": 2,
        "value": 1
      }
    ];
    var data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      })
      .entries(dataset);

    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(d3.range(data.length))
      .rangeRound([0, w])
      .paddingInner(0.05);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d3.max(d.values, e => e.value))])
      .range([0, h]);

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.idx);
      })
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.value);
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! i mean the explanation, not Canadian singer. yet I'm still trying to figure out in which step did the small multiple magic happen. the noob in me doesn't understand if we are appending svgs of 500 width, why aren't they overlapping, what makes them spread out in a matrix?

Comment: @santoku That's just CSS and positioning. Google "inline" and "block" display.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are selecting a DOM element with id = "vis" which is not present in dom.
 Try adding a element with id vis in dom.

```
<div id='vis'></div>
```